# JMustanGo set-up

Tags: java, installation, cluster-computing, hp-ux

We maintained a working JMustanGo HPUX instance. However, we are migrating to HPUX 11i v3 VSE-OE  and need to redeploy I don't seem to find any information on how to setup JMustanGo node. Can anyone provide some useful tips?